# Why is the pandas.DataFrame.cov() method orders of magnitude faster than numpy.dot(...) for the same data?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas

I was calculating covariance run times like this in ipython

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # create data frame set
>>> df = get_data()
>>> df.shape
(4795, 1000)
>>> %timeit df.cov()
10 loops, best of 3: 99.5 ms per loop
>>> mat = np.matrix(df.values)
>>> %timeit np.dot(mat.transpose(), mat)
1 loops, best of 3: 1min per loop
```

Comment: How does `np.cov` do with your data?

Comment: Ah, looks like it's more performant, though still a good bit slower. 663ms rather than 1min.

Comment: Are the results the same?

Comment: Results are not the same for me, and that's not a covariance formula in any event.  I did play around a little and regardless of that, the speed seems about the same between the two methods when I run it.  Can you recreate this example with reproducible data?  e.g. `np.random.randn(4795,1000)`

Comment: Does your data contain null values? Because Panda's cov formula calls np.cov, there shouldn't be a substantial difference
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/f929bc43d2923ae56ed4f94a786dd88df0937a77/pandas/core/frame.py#L4121

Comment: Oh wait, your matrix must already be in the form of differences from the mean (by column)?  It would be good to show that step to make it easier for others to reproduce.  In any event, really tough to imagine how you are seeing that huge difference in speed.

Comment: Hm, they do not appear to be the same. They even have different shapes. I have to head out, but I'll revisit make sure I didn't munge the data set on this trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've figured out the why of the observed speed difference. . . but not the why of the why. I'll update when I find that.

This is the answer to: "Why is the DataFrame.cov method so much faster than converting to a numpy matrix and using the np.cov or np.dot method?"

The DataFrame data type was int64. When it was converted to a numpy matrix using

```
mat = np.matrix(df.to_matrix())
```

The resulting 'mat' object is also of type int64.

Under the hood, the DataFrame.cov method converts its matrix to float64 before calling numpy's covariance method.

When running timeit's on numpy ndarrays or matrices of dtype int64, you see the same performance lag. On my machine with a dataset of shape (16497, 5000) int64 operations do not complete and sometimes crash with memory errors. float64 completes in seconds.

So, the short answer is the reason the numpy.dot method above is slower than the DataFrame.cov one is the datatypes were different.

I'm going to investigate why this gap exists.

Comment: I suspect the 'why of the why' lies in the underlying implementation using SSE for floating point: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/306267